# 3 images as div's background

Tags: html, css

I have a big issue. 
I'm trying to put 3 images as a div background. All is fine, but I can't push them to cover div. When they are next to each other there is a gap between them. css background-size: cover, cover, cover; is not working. How to make that the 3 images cover the whole div without any gap between them?

```
<div id="top_part">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="advert">
            <h1><span>Advertise something here</span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
 #advert {
    border-color: rgb(254, 46, 49);
    border-width: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/image1.jpg), url(images/image2.jpg), url(images/image3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left, center, right;
    background-size: 400px 400px, 400px 400px, 400px 400px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

I managed to do this only with a static size and I will have to use media queries for mobile friendly....

link on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okfj5fos/)

Comment: Please reproduce this issue on jsfiddle.net and then show us.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/zkpsd0jg/2/  are you looking something like tthis one ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all 3 images will have same size, then you can use 33% per width of each image and 34% for the center one. So it can looks like `background-size: 33% 100%, 34% 100%, 33% 100%;`.

Here I made an example what I mean.  Hope this one will help you.

```css
#advert {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/150x200/00ff00), url(https://placehold.it/250x200/00ffff), url(https://placehold.it/350x200/0000ff);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: left, center, right;
  background-size: 33% 100%, 34% 100%, 33% 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="advert"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.centerDiv{
     width: 60%; 
     height:200px; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     background-color:#FFA500 ; 
     } 

.div1 { 
     width: 33%; 
     height:200px; 
     background-color:#A52A2A ; 
     float:left; 
     } 
.div2 { 
     width: 34%; 
     height:200px; 
     background-color:#FFA500 ; 
     float:left; 
     }
.div3 {
    width: 33%; 
    height:200px; 
    background-color:#008000 ; 
    float:left; 
    }
```

---

```
   <div class="centerDiv">
     <div class="div1">
       </div>
        <div class="div2"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="div3"> 
      </div>
     </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/razia/89jvnLbq/

Please check this link:-http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/center-div.html

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this, for priority if need repeat middle image, must be write it before left image:

```css
.toolbar {
      background-image: url("../../../assets/images/chrome-bar-left.png"),
        url("../../../assets/images/chrome-bar-right2.png"),
        url("../../../assets/images/chrome-bar-center.png");
      background-size: auto 50px, auto 50px, auto 50px;
      background-position:  left, right, center ;
      height: 50px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
    }
```